# Pass category ID to block in XML file and get that category products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

This will return all the products. But I want to pass category id and get that category product.
I have also tried category_id="3" in a block like

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" category_id="3" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

But this has no effect. Any solution?

Comment: Please refer to this -- http://docs.mageplaza.com/product-slider-m2/how-to-display-product-ids.html

Comment: @YoYoRoshan i have tried this before

Answer (score 1):

We can pass id in argument tag. seen the code sniped below

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
         <arguments>
                <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
         </arguments>
    </block>
```